# Why binding parameters in an inline query or subquery generates multiple execution plans?

Tags: php, sql-server, parameters, binding

> This 2 examples are tested in php 7.1 with sql server 2008 r2
> Example 1:

```
<?php 
    $pdoMssql = new \PDO('dblib:host=HOST;dbname=DB_NAME;charset=utf8;', 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
    $pdoMssql->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdoMssql->beginTransaction();
    $strq = 'select id_some_table from some_table where id_some_table = :valor';
    $stmt = $pdoMssql->prepare($strq);
    for ($index = 0; $index < 3000; $index++) {
        $stmt->bindValue(':valor', $index, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $pdoMssql->commit();
```

> Result: This creates 1 execution plan and uses it 3000 times, which is great!
> Example 2:

```
<?php 
        $pdoMssql = new \PDO('dblib:host=HOST;dbname=DB_NAME;charset=utf8;', 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
        $pdoMssql->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdoMssql->beginTransaction();
        $strq = 'select id_some_table from ( select id_some_table from some_table ) x where id_some_table = :valor';
        $stmt = $pdoMssql->prepare($strq);
        for ($index = 0; $index < 3000; $index++) {
            $stmt->bindValue(':valor', $index, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
        }

        $pdoMssql->commit();
```

> Result: This creates 1 execution plan per cycle!
>
> Thank you very much

Comment: Can you share your execution plan?  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Your queries are different (and the second one is very obtuse). They should yield the same resultset and plan but, given the names involved, it is likely that you have altered the queries for posting. Is that the case?

Comment: Sure: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyEka0glP

Comment: with the first example i get only 1 execution plan. with the second i get one plan for every single value!

Comment: @SMor 
That's right, I tried to simplify the code, the problem is when ran "select * from (select * from table where value =: value) x" , it converts the parameter to literal and "concatenates" it as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was dblib, with sqlsrv driver this does not happen, thank you very much everyone.
[here a guide to install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac)

and problem solved!